# Unable to connect to database using OCILIB on Visual studio C program

Tags: c, oracle, visual-studio-2019, ocilib

I'm trying to connect to database using OCILIB in C program on Visual studio. I've installed OCILIB package using Nuget packages.

I have written below program to test my connection

```
void err_handler(OCI_Error* err)
{
    printf
    (
        "code  : ORA-%05i\n"
        "msg   : %s\n"
        "sql   : %s\n",
        OCI_ErrorGetOCICode(err),
        OCI_ErrorGetString(err),
        OCI_GetSql(OCI_ErrorGetStatement(err))
    );
}

int main()
{
    OCI_Connection* cn;
    if (!OCI_Initialize(err_handler, NULL, OCI_ENV_DEFAULT))
    {
        printf("OCI Initialzation issue");
        return 1;
    }
    
    printf("trying to create connection\n");
    cn = OCI_ConnectionCreate("localhost:1521/xe", "aravind", "aravind", OCI_SESSION_DEFAULT);

    if (cn)
    {

        printf("connected!!");
    }
    else
    {
        OCI_Error* err = OCI_GetLastError();
        printf("errcode <%hi>, errmsg <%s>\n", OCI_ErrorGetOCICode(err), OCI_ErrorGetString(err));
        printf("NOT connected!!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

error handler output:

```
code  : ORA-00000
msg   : E
sql   : (null)
OCI Initialzation issue
```

I've tried all below connection types but no luck

```
cn = OCI_ConnectionCreate("<ip>:1521/xe", "aravind", "aravind", OCI_SESSION_DEFAULT);
cn = OCI_ConnectionCreate("<full connection string from tnsnames>", "aravind", "aravind", OCI_SESSION_DEFAULT);
```

Can anyone please help me out on this?

Comment: You need to catch the exception. This will reveal the exact ORA- error message. Are you sure port is 1522 ? Default is 1521. Are you able to connect using sqlplus?

Comment: Is the port number of the service name correct?  I've only ever used it without a port number.  Presumably all the TNS incantations have already been done.

Comment: yes, port is right, it's 1522

Comment: I fixed this issue, it was problem with oracle client.

Answer (score 0):

Provide an error handler to OCI_Initialize().
It will get called by OCILIB and the error details will be returned by OCI_ErrorGetString().